# Pedra,papel,Tesoura

Tags: javascript

iniciante - Código é uma interação como o jogo pedra, papel e tesoura que deveria acontecer no alerta de paginas do chrome, problema é que quando abro o html não me não me apresenta nada.

```
<script>

while(true){
    jogador1 = prompt("Jogador 1: Digite pedra, papel ou tesoura");
    jogador2 = prompt("Jogador 2: Digite pedra, papel ou tesoura");

if (jogador1 == "pedra") {
     if (jogador2 == "tesoura") {
        alert ("Pedra quebra tesoura");
    } else if (jogador2 == "papel"){
        alert ("Papel envolve a Pedra");
    } else if (jogador2 == "pedra") {
        alert ("Empate");
    }

}
 else if (jogador1 == "tesoura") {
    if (jogador2 == "pedra") {
        alert ("Pedra quebra tesoura");
    } else if (jogador2 == papel){
        alert ("tesoura corta papel");
    } else if (jogadoe2 == "tesoura") {
        alert ("Empate");
    }
}

 else if (jogador1 == "papel"){
    if (jogador2 == "pedra") {
        alert (Papel envolve pedra);
    }else if (jogador2 == tesoura) {
        alert ("Tesoura corta papel");
    }else if (jogador2 == "papel")  {
        alert ("Empate");
    }

}

}

</script>
```

Comment: Abra o console do navegador, deve ter algum erro.

Comment: Erro de digitação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AO executar o código aqui, percebi o erro no console do navegador:

> teste.html:29 
> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Linha 29 tinha:

```
alert (Papel envolve pedra);
```

Mudei para:

```
alert ("Papel envolve pedra");
```

E tudo funcionou, mas acho que alinha 30 também precisava de atenção:

```
<script>

    while(true){
        jogador1 = prompt("Jogador 1: Digite pedra, papel ou tesoura");
        jogador2 = prompt("Jogador 2: Digite pedra, papel ou tesoura");

        if (jogador1 == "pedra") {
            if (jogador2 == "tesoura") {
                alert ("Pedra quebra tesoura");
            } else if (jogador2 == "papel"){
                alert ("Papel envolve a Pedra");
            } else if (jogador2 == "pedra") {
                alert ("Empate");
            }

        }
        else if (jogador1 == "tesoura") {
            if (jogador2 == "pedra") {
                alert ("Pedra quebra tesoura");
            } else if (jogador2 == papel){
                alert ("tesoura corta papel");
            } else if (jogadoe2 == "tesoura") {
                alert ("Empate");
            }
        }

        else if (jogador1 == "papel"){
            if (jogador2 == "pedra") {
                alert ("Papel envolve pedra");
            }else if (jogador2 == "tesoura") {
                alert ("Tesoura corta papel");
            }else if (jogador2 == "papel")  {
                alert ("Empate");
            }

        }

    }

</script>
```

Comment: deu boa agradece, vlw

Comment: Então marca a resposta como correta, e setinha pra cima ;)